# Doesn't work in Runtime form child form closing method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a method to close all child forms in windows application C#.
There are no errors but it doesn't work in runtime!

```
 private void closechildform(Form  f)
    {
        foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            
            
                frm.SendToBack();
            frm.Hide();
                return;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: The return stops the function in the first iteration of the foreach loop, remove that line if you want all child forms to close

Comment: If you want to _Close_ the child window, why not call `Close` on them. By the way, you need to describe your problem better than _"There are no errors but it doesn't work in runtime"_. Saying _doesn't work_ doesn't help us understand your issue at all

Comment: Did you step through your code in the debugger? The problem that @armin eyeballed should have jumped out at you if you had debugged your code

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for responding! I did so but still didn't work! By the way, I described as it was! The method didn't do what I wanted! What's the problem with that!(I'm a newbie!)

Comment: @Armin  I did delete return! Still didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `return` to outside the `foreach` loop. Because in your existing code it will return after first iteration.

**FYI**: If the method is void then there’s no need of `return` inside the method.

Comment: I did delete return nut still didn't work!